# Migradoc and PDfSharp add line after text till the end of the page

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

I have this so far:

```
Table table = CreateBaseTable();
Row row = table.AddRow();
    {
        row.Cells[0].AddParagraph().AddFormattedText(text, bold);
    }
```

I would like to have a line after this text, for example:

This Is a Header ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
but not dotted.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a line to the right of your text: use a tab stop with a line as filling (that's how it looks like in your question but I presume this is not what you want).

If you want to have the line below the text: set the border of the table cell (or table row). In your case, set the bottom border width to the desired width, set the width of other borders (top, left, right) to 0.

For the row, try code like this:

```
row.Borders.Bottom.Visible = true;
row.Borders.Bottom.Width = 1;
```

Edit: Here's sample code for the tab stop:

```
paragraph = section.AddParagraph("Hello, World!");
paragraph.Format.TabStops.ClearAll();
paragraph.Format.TabStops.AddTabStop("16cm", TabAlignment.Right, TabLeader.Lines);
paragraph.AddTab();
```

I should have tested that before pointing that option out. The line is drawn at the base, so it looks like
The Header_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*____**

TabLeader also offers Dashes (which you don't want) or MiddleDots (which you didn't ask for either).
So I'm afraid there is no simple solution to get exactly what you want.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I don't want it under; as I said in the post, I want the line after the text. So I have the text, then when the last word ends I want a line to start and go to the end of the line. The way it looks like in my question is like a dotted line, because I couldn't write a full line with the text. So I would like a full line after the word (on the right side of the last word). So could you please give me an example of the "tab stop with a line as filling"? Thank you

Comment: Sample code for TabStops added. I'm afraid they do not do exactly what you want.

Comment: ok, thanks, I will mark as answer then. Answer as in it cannot be done. OK?

Comment: Answer is: I don't know a simple solution. (MigraDoc is Open Source, so there always is a way to do it if you have enough time.) MigraDoc is much like Word. Could you achieve that line with Word?